# How to convert the result set of this native query to a list of DTOs

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, dto

I have the following DTO:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeHierarchyDto {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer supervisorId;
    private Integer level;
    private String branch;
    private Integer position;
}
```

And then later I have this native query:

```
    public List<EmployeeDto> getAllSubordinateSubordinates(Integer employeeId) {
        if (employeeId == null) {
            employeeId = getCeo().getId();
        }
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        String sqlString = "select t.id, " +
                "t.supervisor_id, " +
                "t.level, " +
                "t.branch, " +
                "t.pos " +
                "FROM connectby('public.employee'::text, 'id'::text, 'supervisor_id'::text, 'last_name'::text, " + "'" + employeeId +
                "'::text, 0, '~'::text) t(id int, supervisor_id int, level integer, branch text, pos integer);";
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sqlString);
        List hierarchyList = q.getResultList();
        List<EmployeeDto> employeeDtoList = new ArrayList<>();

        return employeeDtoList;
    }
```

When I debug the code and copy the sql string generated into a db console, this is what I get if for instance the frontend passed the id of 93:

```
select t.id, t.supervisor_id, t.level, t.branch, t.pos FROM connectby('public.employee'::text, 'id'::text, 'supervisor_id'::text, 'last_name'::text, '93'::text, 0, '~'::text) t(id int, supervisor_id int, level integer, branch text, pos integer);
```

The above query executes 100% correct in the db console.

EDIT:
The exact error is:

```
11:39:50,711 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
11:39:50,714 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
  Position: 88
```

The 42601 points to a PostgreSQL syntax error, however if the string that will become the native query is copied from the debugger and pasted into a db console it works without problem.

Why would this be? And secondly, how can I map the result set to a list of EmployeeHierarchyDto's

Comment: `I get a weird error`. Should we guess it?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Sorry friend, no need to guess. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems releated to the syntax used by postgres' cast operator.
That’s because of the :: type cast operator conflicts with the JPA : named parameter syntax.

There are a bunch of workaround to that, see [cast-operator-issue-with-jpa](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-do-solve-the-postgresql-cast-operator-issue-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Thanks, escaping the :: symbols with \\:\\: worked perfectly!